# Defining global variable in Perl with `strict`

Tags: perl

I have the following package/files structure:
The first one:

```
# package1
package Package1;

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);

return 1;
```

The second one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use package1;

foreach $a (@array)
{
    print $a;    
}
```

Unfortunately, I have the following error:

> Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at Package1.pm

I tried to define `@array` as `our`, but it didn't help.
Also I can not define it as just `@array`, because of `strict`.

Is there any legal way to make global variables with `strict`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package code: (our instead of my)

```
package Package1;

use strict;
use warnings;

our @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);

return 1;
```

script code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Package1;

foreach my $a (@Package1::array)
{
    print $a;    
}
```

Also, you could use [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Exporter-5.68/lib/Exporter.pm) module to control the functions and variables into the user's namespace